# PHP Slim Framework: PUT method "Unexpected token S"

Tags: php, api, frameworks, slim

### **Greetings**

I'm new with the Slim Micro Framework, and not a pro in PHP. I've been looking how similar answer i could relate with my problem and haven't had good results.

My problem is, that i'm trying to update the database trough an API, with the PUT method that this framework offers, and every time and running the request, i get

> `Unexpected token S`

When the request header is:

> `Status: 200 OK Show explanation Loading time: 422
>   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36
>   Origin: chrome-extension://hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo
>   Content-Type: application/json 
>   Accept: */*
>   Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
>   Accept-Language: es,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6`
>   
>   and the response header i get
>   
>   `Date: Mon, 24 Mar 2014 20:05:14 GMT 
>   Server: Apache 
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
>   Vary: Accept-Encoding 
>   Content-Encoding: gzip 
>   Content-Length: 98 
>   Keep-Alive: timeout=10, max=500
>   Connection: Keep-Alive
>   Content-Type: application/json`

### Basically this is the code:

```
 $app->put('/update-user/:id', 'updateUser'); 
 function updateUser($id){

$app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
$app->contentType('application/json');
$app->response()->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
$app->response()->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    $response = $app->response();
$body = $app->request()->getBody();
$user = json_decode($body);

// $response = array();

$sql = "update usr SET experiencie=:experiencie WHERE id=:id";
try {
    $db = PDOConnection();
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql) or die("Error: query preparation to database failed.");

    $stmt->bindParam("experiencie", $user->experiencie);

    $stmt->bindParam("id", $id) or die("Error:: fallo en parámetro -> id");
    $stmt->execute();
    $db = null;
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $response['error'] = false;
        $response['text'] = '"Good!"';
    } else {
         $response['error'] = true;
         $response['text'] = '"Bad!"';
     }

     echo json_encode($response);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    error_log($e->getMessage(), 3, '/var/tmp/php.log');
    echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
 }
}
```

I get `status 200 ok`, but not any response if either good or bad, and the database does not reflects any changes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: **sorry** for the syntax errors, i had to edit the main code so i can ask the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the error occurs while trying to decipher your hand-rolled *error* JSON. Simply put, never produce JSON manually. Change your exception handler to this...

```
catch (PDOException $e) {
    error_log($e->getMessage(), 3, '/var/tmp/php.log');
    http_response_code(500);
    echo json_encode(['error' => ['text' => $e->getMessage()]]);
}
```

Assuming you have PDO set to throw exceptions, get rid of the `or die()` statements.

You are also calling `$stmt->execute()` twice as well as closing the connection before you're done with it. Your code will work better as...

```
try {
    if (!isset($user->experiencie)) {
        throw new Exception('Missing "experiencie" request parameter');
    }

    $db = PDOConnection();
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bindParam(':experiencie', $user->experiencie);

    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $response['error'] = false;
        $response['text'] = 'Good!';
    } else {
         $response['error'] = true;
         $response['text'] = 'Bad!';
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    error_log($e->getMessage(), 3, '/var/tmp/php.log');
    http_response_code(500);
    echo json_encode(['error' => ['text' => $e->getMessage()]]);
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks, that solved that problem, tho it `took me into another` in which i would have to ask a whole different question.